# Why doesn't my timer print every second that passes?

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks

I wanted to make a code that printed every second that passes in my timer for a total of 30 seconds (hence why I made a for loop) however it just repeatedly prints 1, so I am guessing that my for loop isn't working and it isn't appending 1 to the variable score. Any suggestions on what I should do? Thanks.

```
public class TimerSchedule {

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    // creating timer task, timer  
    Timer t = new Timer();  
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {  
        @Override  
        public void run() {  
           for(int i=0; i<30;i++)  
            {  
            int score = 0;
            score ++;
            System.out.println(score);
            }  
        };  
    };  
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt,0,1000);    
       }  
    }
```

Comment: Three problems: First the whole `run`-method is executed each second. Second, in each loop-iteration, you create a new variable `score` and initialize it with the value `0`. Third, the scheduled tasks does run indefinetly, not only 30 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is printing `1` is that you have put the following two statements inside the `for` loop:

```
int score = 0;
System.out.println(score);
```

The first one is resetting `score` in every iteration while the second one prints the updated value of `score` in each iteration. The first one should be put outside `run()`. Also, you need to cancel the timer when the value of `score` reaches `30`.

Given below is the updated code:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
            int score = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(++score);
                if (score == 30) {
                    t.cancel();
                }
            };
        };
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 1000);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
...
...
...
29
30
```